# Difference between "lucro" and "fines de lucro"

Tags: vocabulario

There's an election where I live, and the ballot is in English and Spanish. Each candidate's current profession is listed under their name, in both languages. One caught my attention for how long it was in Spanish.

> **Steve Poizner**
>   Party Preference: None
>   Preferencia de Partido: Ninguna
>   Businessman/Non-Profit Director
>   Empresario/Director de Organización Sin Fines de Lucro

[image]

His profession is Businessman/Non-Profit Director in English, and 'Empresario/Director de Organizactión Sin Fines de Lucro' in Spanish.

I have a rudimentary knowledge of Spanish, and I know *fin*(*es*) in the sense of "end." From some googling, both the word *lucro* and the phrase *fines de lucro* seem to mean "profit." What's the difference?

As a side question, is that a reasonable way to say "Non-Profit Director" in Spanish, or is this an awkward literal translation?

Comment: It's the English title that is awkward here. It would sound more natural if they wrote "Director of Non-Profit Organization." If this were the case, the Spanish translation is what you would expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of what keeps things short in English is that we commonly refer to non-profit organizations as simply "non-profits".  While Spanish grammar allows for that, it's not so commonly used that people would understand that the implied noun is an organization.

The more normal translation is *sin ánimo de lucro* (without [an] animus of profit), but *fines* (ends) is often used instead of *ánimo*.  We use this sense of *fines* in English in expressions like *the ends justify the means*.  Basically, the *ends* that are desired (the goal) is profit, and the organization in Spanish is said to be without such goal.

There isn't really a great way to translate that title and stay so short, although if we knew the specific type of non-profit we could, by shortening it to an ONG (an NGO) or maybe calling it a *sociedad benéfica* (charitable organization).

Comment: Yo may also say "no lucrativa".

Comment: @roetnig I haven't heard that used before, and I wouldn't recommend it as *lucrativo* is generally synonymous with *rentable*, meaning that it actually produces profit (a for-profit business may not necessarily actually produce profit)

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizaci%C3%B3n_sin_%C3%A1nimo_de_lucro

Comment: http://www.tambientienesderecho.com/tag/que-es-asociacion-no-lucrativa/

Comment: @roetnig puede ser que exista, y que se use, pero lo dicho, no lo usaría en una traducción como aquella porque si yo viese «organización lucrativa» lo entendería como «organización que es muy rentable» y «organización no lucrativa» como «organización que es poco rentable» o incluso «con rentabilidad en negativa».  No hay ambigüedad empleando «con fines/ánimo de lucro».  Quizás si alguno quisiese usar un adjetivo único y sin ambigüedad podría inventar *lucrófila*, pero en tal caso sería mejor emplear «plutófila»

Comment: Bueno, "no lucrativa" es perfectamente válido y es un término legalmente empleado en muchos países, incluido España. Haz una busqueda en google.